Parallelization performance using OpenMP directives for GPU offloading
I have CG kernel that I need to to perform parallelization using OpenMP directives for GPU offloading.
The code Copied from Github: https://github.com/GMAP/NPB-CPP/tree/master/NPB-OMP/CG.
The partial code that is written below is most probably what takes 90% of the program performence.
/* the conj grad iteration loop */
for(cgit = 1; cgit <= cgitmax; cgit++){
    /*
     * ---------------------------------------------------------------------
     * q = A.p
     * the partition submatrix-vector multiply: use workspace w
     * ---------------------------------------------------------------------
     * 
     * note: this version of the multiply is actually (slightly: maybe %5) 
     * faster on the sp2 on 16 nodes than is the unrolled-by-2 version 
     * below. on the Cray t3d, the reverse is TRUE, i.e., the 
     * unrolled-by-two version is some 10% faster.  
     * the unrolled-by-8 version below is significantly faster
     * on the Cray t3d - overall speed of code is 1.5 times faster.
     */

    #pragma omp single nowait
    {
        d = 0.0;
        /*
         * --------------------------------------------------------------------
         * save a temporary of rho
         * --------------------------------------------------------------------
         */
        rho0 = rho;
        rho = 0.0;
    }

    #pragma omp for nowait
    for(j = 0; j < lastrow - firstrow + 1; j++){
        suml = 0.0;
        for(k = rowstr[j]; k < rowstr[j+1]; k++){
            suml += a[k]*p[colidx[k]];
        }
        q[j] = suml;
    }

    /*
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------
     * obtain p.q
     * --------------------------------------------------------------------
     */

It's university exercise and we were told to focus on changing the pragmas.
I have already tried to use #pragma omp target,#pragma omp target enter data,#pragma omp target teams distribute parallel for and many more suggested solutions on the internet, and NON of them help.
Do you have any idea how can I reduce the runtime?

The directive you use are CPU ones not GPU ones. Also please consider declaring variables in loops so to avoid race condition in your code due to the use of shared variables instead of private ones. The alternative is to manually specify which variables are private using private(your_variable) clause. Here suml likely cause a race condition since it should be shared between iteration. It is hard to know though since the provided code is incomplete (which also means we cannot reproduce the problem).

As for the "NON of them help", it does not give much information since we do not know what did you tried with GPU directives (i.e. #pragma omp target, etc.). Did you check your GPU was actually used? Maybe OpenMP is not well configured on the target machine and directives are just ignored. We can't know.

The main problem of your restricted focus is that you omitted where your code actually spawns the concurrency. Looking at the GitHub code, the parallel region is even spawned outside of the function you are looking at. That's where you should start looking for replacing parallel by target.

Since the threads are spawned outside the function, all variables are local to each task and there should be no race on suml.
